# Restrict draggable div element within viewport

Tags: javascript, html

I have a working code which would drag and drop the div element. However, I am unable to understand how can i restrict the drag movement within the viewport width and height.

The element is being cut off when moved towards the corners of the webpage.
I have not done anything similar before and I cannot use Jquery to achive my results. Any suggestions on this please

```js
    //Make the DIV element draggagle:
    dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));
    
    function dragElement(elmnt) {
      var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
      if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
        /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
        document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
      } else {
        /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
        elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
      }
    
      function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
      }
    
      function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // calculate the new cursor position:
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        // set the element's new position:
        elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
        elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
      }
    
      function closeDragElement() {
        /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
      }
    }
```

```css
    #mydiv {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 9;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    }
    
    #mydivheader {
      padding: 10px;
      cursor: move;
      z-index: 10;
      background-color: #2196F3;
      color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>
    
    <p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV element</p>
    
    <div id="mydiv">
      <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
      <p>Move</p>
      <p>this</p>
      <p>DIV</p>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what is u r need  exactly ??

Comment: I would need to stop the drag event once it reaches webpage corners. Currently, it get dragged completely and get hidden when moved to the edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's only a partial answer but gives you a general idea. You have to calculate the maximum values where not to go beyond, based on window size and your div size. This version is missing some things, for example, it won't work until you set it to "full page" because the div is already out of bounds when running the snippet. To solve this, you could calculate if you're going up and allow it when out of the lower bound, etc. It could also be improved by using a more absolute mouse position instead of relative movement, for the case the mouse goes too far out of the viewport.

The `-1` on the maximum values is a security because of the border.

Good luck!

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    var winW = document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth,
      winH = document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
    maxX = winW - elmnt.offsetWidth - 1,
      maxY = winH - elmnt.offsetHeight - 1;
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    //console.log((elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1), maxY, (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1), maxX);
    if ((elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) <= maxY && (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) >= 0) {
      elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    }
    if ((elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) <= maxX && (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) >= 0) {
      elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    }
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>

  <p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV element</p>

  <div id="mydiv">
    <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
    <p>Move</p>
    <p>this</p>
    <p>DIV</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

EDIT: removed `window.innerHeight ||`  and `window.innerWidth ||`  so it works with a scrollbar

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Of course it works well :)

Comment: You're welcome, always glad to help.. you can consider accepting the answer if you think it answers the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

minor changes to elementDrag() function should do the trick.
check it out...

```js
    //Make the DIV element draggagle:
    dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));
    
    function dragElement(elmnt) {
      var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
      if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
        /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
        document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
      } else {
        /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
        elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
      }
    
      function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
      }
    
      function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // calculate the new cursor position:
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        // calculate the max cursor position:
        var xMax = window.innerWidth - elmnt.offsetWidth;
        var yMax = window.innerHeight - elmnt.offsetHeight;
        // set the element's new position:
        if ((elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) >= 0 && (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) <= xMax) {
          elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
          pos3 = e.clientX;
        }
        if ((elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) >= 0 && (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) <= yMax) {
          elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
          pos4 = e.clientY;
        }
      }
    
      function closeDragElement() {
        /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
      }
    }
```

```css
    #mydiv {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 9;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    }
    
    #mydivheader {
      padding: 10px;
      cursor: move;
      z-index: 10;
      background-color: #2196F3;
      color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>
    
    <p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV element</p>
    
    <div id="mydiv">
      <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
      <p>Move</p>
      <p>this</p>
      <p>DIV</p>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```